# How to insert a custom inscription ID of a user in mysqli?

Tags: php, mysqli, uniqueidentifier

I'm working on a school manager script. 
I don't know how to insert a custom unique id of subscription...

I just use this function to show it's unique subscription's id when showing his/her full informations from the database:

```
$year = date('Y');
$ID = substr($student->dateNaissance,8,10).$student->id_etudiant."/".$year;
```

The function is combined of 3 things:

- The 2 last digits of the year of birth (example: 01/01/1981.. i take only this -->81 using the substr function)
- The row id from the table on the database (ex: 50).
- And the year of subcription(example: 2013)

all that gives me , for example, as result 8150/2013

what i want here is when inserting the student data into the database , i want this unique ID to be inserted as well..

### The problem here is i don't know how to get the last id of a row !

Yeah, I tried to insert the student data and then update the id_subscription using this:

```
if(isset(....){ 
...... 
    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO table (a,b,c, ...etc) VALUES('','',''..etc)"); 
    $year = date('Y'); 
    $mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table_name"); 
    $studentID = $mysqli_insert_id(); 
    $ID = substr($student->dateNaissance,8,10).$ID."/".$year; 
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE table_name SET id_subscription = $ID"); 
}
```

But its not working :\

By the way: in my table Im using an auto_increment id + the subscription_id in which i want to insert the customized id I showed above.

Comment: If you want last id or record use this `select * from table order by id desc` or use `mysqli_insert_id` or `mysql_insert_id`

Comment: `$mysqli_query` and `$mysqli_insert_id()`? wonky code.. hopefully just typos.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that row id is an auto_increment field, then you'd have to do it in two stages:

1. start transaction
2. insert everything into the DB **EXCEPT** your id field
3. use last_insert_id() to get the mysql-generated ID field
4. build your own id field
5. update the record with this new id
6. commit the transaction.

Comment: don't put code chunks into a comment. totally unreadable. you can edit your question and append it.

Answer (score 0):

On Database Structure:
1. you can use auto-incremented primary key in your table and store the data(student_id) as a seperate column(recommended).

On getting 'the last id of a row':
1. Use mysql_insert_id() .. [check this out](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-insert-id.php)